# Ruby (Rails): export db data for SPSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, spss

I have a Rails application to do web surveys. It stores answers to multiple-choices (fixnum) questions into sqlite3. Is there any ruby gem that I can use to export my data into spss format ? I'd like to be able to export for SPSS version prior of 16/16 or up.

My SPSS export needs to include two files:

- a syntax file (survey_name_SPSS_syntax_file.sps)
- a data file (survey_name_SPSS_data_file.dat)

I can change dbms if needed.

Comment: Can't SPSS read CSV files?  I would recommend that over rolling your own.  See the standard CSV library and/or faster-csv.

Comment: Yes It can but my customers said they like to have a "straight to the point" format, and they know nothing more than a little of SPSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to roll my own solution based on the limesurvey spss export function page. I'll let everyone here know, If and how I achieve It. :)

Comment: have you found anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pspp (gnu console tool for Linux) to convert CSV and a syntax file with the codes to SPSS. http://benpfaff.org/~blp/pspp.pdf